# PHP - transform arrays multidimensional keys

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I was wondering if there's any PHP function or combinations to transform arrays like this

```
[Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => name
            [1] => value
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => John Doe
            [1] => Married
        )

    [2] => Array
    (
        [0] => John Wick
        [1] => Single
    )
)
```

I want transform the first index value to be others index, or something like this

```
[Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [name] => John Doe
                [value] => Married
            )
    
        [1] => Array
            (
                [name] => John Wick
                [value] => Single
            )
        )
```

Comment: There is no function, but there are several.  Try something.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is something you could use:

```php
$replacements = array_shift($arr);
array_walk($arr, function(&$element) use ($replacements) {
    array_walk($element, function($value, $key) use ($replacements, &$element) {
        if (array_key_exists($key, $replacements)) {
            $element[$replacements[$key]] = $value;
            unset($element[$key]);
        }
    });
});
```

It removes the first element of the array and stores it as a replacements array. Then, it walks over all the elements in the array and checks if the index of the currently looped over inner array exists in replacements. If it does, it adds a new element to the array and removes the old one. Check [this 3v4l](https://3v4l.org/SjOZg) for a working example.